# OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long:

Tags: python, xml

I need to convert a web page to XML (using Python `3.4.3`). If I write the contents of the URL to a file then I can read and parse it perfectly but if I try to read directly from the web page I get the following error in my terminal:

> File "./AnimeXML.py", line 22, in 
>           xml = ElementTree.parse (xmlData)
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1187, in parse
>           tree.parse(source, parser)
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 587, in parse
>           source = open(source, "rb")
>       OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long:

**My python code:**

```
# AnimeXML.py
#! /usr/bin/Python

# Import xml parser.
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

# XML to parse.
sampleUrl = "http://cdn.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/api.xml?anime=16989"

# Read the xml as a file.
content = urlopen (sampleUrl)

# XML content is stored here to start working on it.
xmlData = content.readall().decode('utf-8')

# Close the file.
content.close()

# Start parsing XML.
xml = ElementTree.parse (xmlData)

# Get root of the XML file.
root = xml.getroot()

for info in root.iter("info"):
    print (info.attrib)
```

Is there any way I can fix my code so that I can read the web page directly into python without getting this error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As explained in the [Parsing XML](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml) section of the `ElementTree` docs:

> We can import this data by reading from a file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

> Or directly from a string:

```
root = ET.fromstring(country_data_as_string)
```

You're passing the whole XML contents as a giant pathname. Your XML file is probably bigger than 2K, or whatever the maximum pathname size is for your platform, hence the error. If it weren't, you'd just get a different error about there being no directory named `[everything up to the first / in your XML file]`.

Just use [`fromstring`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring) instead of `parse`.

Or, notice that [`parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse) can take a file object, not just a filename. And the thing returned by [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) is a file object.

---

Also notice the very next line in that section:

> `fromstring()` parses XML from a string directly into an `Element`, which is the root element of the parsed tree. Other parsing functions may create an `ElementTree`.

So, you don't want that `root = tree.getroot()` either.

---

So:

```
# ...
content.close()
root = ElementTree.fromstring(xmlData)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is solved now. I'm newbie with python.

Comment: What is the difference between using "parse" and "fromstring" ?

Comment: @JasterTDCClan: That's explained in the docs that I both linked and quoted: `parse` takes a filename or a file, `fromstring` takes a string. I don't know how to make that any clearer.

Comment: Thanks ^^, sorry for the problems I cause to you.