# iterate through XML?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.6

What is the easiest way to navigate through XML with python?

```
<html>
 <body>
  <soapenv:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:body>
    <getservicebyidresponse xmlns="http://www.something.com/soa/2.0/SRIManagement">
     <code xmlns="">
      0
     </code>
     <client xmlns="">
      <action xsi:nil="true">
      </action>
      <actionmode xsi:nil="true">
      </actionmode>
      <clientid>
       405965216
      </clientid>
      <firstname xsi:nil="true">
      </firstname>
      <id xsi:nil="true">
      </id>
      <lastname>
       Last Name
      </lastname>
      <role xsi:nil="true">
      </role>
      <state xsi:nil="true">
      </state>
     </client>
    </getservicebyidresponse>
   </soapenv:body>
  </soapenv:envelope>
 </body>
</html>
```

I would go with regex and try to get the values of the lines I need but is there a pythonic way? something like `xml[0][1]` etc?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers mark as duplicate if you want. but do not tell to google in SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to recursively iterate over XML tags in Python using ElementTree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074361/how-to-recursively-iterate-over-xml-tags-in-python-using-elementtree)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @deceze already pointed out, you can use [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) here.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("path_to_xml_file")
root = tree.getroot()
```

You can iterate over all children nodes of root:

```
for child in root.iter():
    if child.tag == 'clientid':
        print(child.tag, child.text.strip())
```

Children are nested, and we can access specific child nodes by index, so `root[0][1]` should work (as long as the indices are correct).

Comment: This gives me `IOError: [Errno 36] File name too long: `

Comment: Kindly refer to this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29891397/2689986.
You are likely passing file contents instead of passing filename to the `ET.parse` function.

Comment: Ok so `root = ET.fromstring(xml)` fixes this, I dont have an XML File

Comment: `for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)`
gives me `('body', {})`

Comment: What is the output that you desire?

Comment: for instance `clientid` ( the value: `405965216`

Comment: Ok I checked your edit, I receive this error now: `AttributeError: _ElementInterface instance has no attribute 'iter'`

Comment: for RHEL stock config (Python 2.6.6) its: `root.getiterator():` now it works, and I understood what I need to do thank you