# How can I remedy "File name too long" when parsing XML file?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I know this has been asked multiple times. I've spent hours looking through different answers and none of them are working for me. 
I'm retrieving xml output from a soap call. I need to be able to parse it and grab elements that are important. 
However, no matter what I try, I keep getting the "File name too long" error.

As of now my code stands at this:

```
import requests
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
def sendRequest():
    url= " ?? "
    headers= {
    "SOAPAction": "??",
    "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
    }
    body="""<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" 
xmlns:urn=\"###\" xmlns:v1=\"###\" xmlns:v11=\"###\" xmlns:v12=\"http://###\">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <urn:MessageHeader version=\"1.0\">
            <MessageID>test</MessageID>
            <CreateDateTime>2013-07-05T10:56:19.701+05:30</CreateDateTime>
            <From app=\"test\" module=\"test\" nodeID=\"test\" systemCode=\"test\"/>
        </urn:MessageHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <v1:SearchInput>
            <v11:Style>
                <v11:StyleAttributes StyleIdentifier=\"NUM\"/>
            </v11:Style>
            <v11:AdvanceFilter WantChildren=\"1\" WantRelationship=\"1\"/>
            <v11:ExtendedFilterInput WantCP=\"1\"/>
        </v1:SearchInput>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"""

    ###  = information masked

    response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
    data = response.text
    with open('output.xml', 'w') as f:
        f.write(data)
    tree = ET.parse(data)
    root = tree.getroot()
    print(root)

send_request()
```

I've tried BeautifulSoup, lxml, saving the xml to a file first, and reading it directly from the call. I've used ET.parse() as well as ET.fromstring(). Have tried using the response itself, as well as the content of the response. All per answers I have seen elsewhere. I'm sure one of the combinations should work, I just haven't figured out which one ;)
I truly do not know how to solve this issue. 
Any help is appreciated.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mdm.py", line 61, in <module>
    send_request()
  File "mdm.py", line 43, in send_request
    tree = ET.parse(data)
  File "/Users/mm/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1197, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/Users/mm/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 587, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> .....
```

Comment: Its a python error? If so, please post the traceback.

Comment: The first step to remedying the problem is to give us the information we need. I don't see anything that would cause a python level "file name too long" error in your code.

Comment: Sorry - error might have helped. Edit posted.

Comment: You want `ET.fromstring(data)`. `ET.parse` takes a file name or file object. It tried to use your xml document as the filename.

Comment: @tdelaney I had tried that originally but got the error "AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getroot' "
But I guess that doesn't mean it didn't succeed in parsing the xml. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891308/oserror-errno-36-file-name-too-long answers the question. I can't mark this a dup because I already voted "needs more detail".

Comment: but, if I can't get the root element, I can't grab other elements that I need. So now what?

Comment: good point. `parse` gives you an `ElementTree` and you need to `getroot` to get the root element. `fromstring` just gives you the root element.

Comment: If you have trouble finding elements, read up on how elementtree handles namespaces http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm#element-tree-representation

Comment: Thanks for your help @tdelaney